# Reading extensionattribute1 ro extensionattribute15 in AzureAd ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, adal, claims

**How can I request more claims from the AzureAd server to populate my ASPNET Core Application..?**

I'm trying to get claims coming through with AzureAd.
We have extensionattribute1 to extensionattribute15 defined in our onprem, and it's being synced. Yet I can't get them when I study the Claims collection in the ClaimsPrincipal object...

I've set the OpenIdConnectOptions with `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` to `true`

I tried changing the manifest, but when trying to do so I can't save them (getting error like´Failed to update application AspNetCoreWebApplicationWithAzureAd. Error details: Request_BadRequest´). Additionally I also have no idea or haven't found documentation on what those values are (string / bool / array of strings)

```
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"optionalClaims": null,
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get this working using the steps in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping. The "Example claims mapping policies" section and the comments have some useful info.

So far I've got about half the claims I've mapped to come over during a login via AzureAD. I'm working with Microsoft support to figure out why its not fully working.

If I can get it going I'll post a fuller series of steps to save someone else the pain in the future! But hopefully this gets you going in the meantime.

PS: I had to set "acceptMappedClaims" to true in the application manifest which hasn't been mentioned in any of the articles I've read.

Comment: Update 18/12/17 - I've been told by MS support that this feature is in public preview and not fully supported yet.